# Usage of groupBy in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I an currently learning spark in python. I had a small question, in other languages like SQL we can simply group a table by specified columns and then perform further operations like sum, count, etc. on them. How do we do this in Spark?

I have schema like :

```
    [name:"ABC", city:"New York", money:"50"]
    [name:"DEF", city:"London", money:"10"]
    [name:"ABC", city:"New York", money:"30"]
    [name:"XYZ", city:"London", money:"20"]
    [name:"XYZ", city:"London", money:"100"]
    [name:"DEF", city:"London", money:"200"]
```

Let's say I want to group this by city, and then perform the sum of money for each name. Something like :

```
    New York ABC 80
    London DEF 210
    London XYZ 120
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL:

```
>>> sc.parallelize([
... {"name": "ABC", "city": "New York", "money":"50"},
... {"name": "DEF", "city": "London",   "money":"10"},
... {"name": "ABC", "city": "New York", "money":"30"},
... {"name": "XYZ", "city": "London",   "money":"20"},
... {"name": "XYZ", "city": "London",   "money":"100"},
... {"name": "DEF", "city": "London",   "money":"200"},
... ]).toDF().registerTempTable("df")

>>> sqlContext.sql("""SELECT name, city, sum(cast(money as bigint)) AS total 
... FROM df GROUP name, city""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's going to make life a whole lot easier, knowing how to execute sql statements within spark.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a Pythonic way as well (or the SQL version @LostInOverflow posted):

```
grouped = df.groupby('city', 'name').sum('money')
```

It looks like your `money` column is strings, so you'll need to cast it as an `int` first (or load it up that way to begin with):

```
df = df.withColumn('money', df['money'].cast('int'))
```

And remember that dataframes are immutable, so both of these require you to assign them to an object (even if it's just back to `df` again), and then use `show` if you want to see the results.

Edit: I should add that you need to create a dataframe first.  For your simple data it's almost the same as the SQL version posted, but you assign it to a dataframe object instead of registering it as a table:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    {"name": "ABC", "city": "New York", "money":"50"},
    {"name": "DEF", "city": "London",   "money":"10"},
    {"name": "ABC", "city": "New York", "money":"30"},
    {"name": "XYZ", "city": "London",   "money":"20"},
    {"name": "XYZ", "city": "London",   "money":"100"},
    {"name": "DEF", "city": "London",   "money":"200"},
    ]).toDF()
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I actually printed the money as char's by mistake, but now I know what to do when they aren't int. Thanks for the help!